# Android Application passing controll or redirect to another application

Tags: android, apk

we have a standalone android application(video portal) once the user click on buy now video, we want redirection to another 
android application(user verification).
The question is , is there any way we redirect control from video portal application to user verification portal. We don't want
user to install two different applications, realizing him that he is using only one application.
Any Suggestions on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: why not make single application from merged source bases?

Comment: user verification application is a third party application and we have to shift control from video portal application to this user verification application. Both are standalone application.

Comment: So you want to use 3rd party application, but don't want user to install it? I think there is something wrong with your design.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an intent with the parameters that will fire the other app if it's installed. If it's not installed you can still link to it to the market to download it like this:

market://details?id=com.fletech.smartbaby.android

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fletech.smartbaby.android

See more details and java example here:
http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#android-app

I suppose you need to pass some parameters to the authentication app, together with the "link" or PendingIntent to an activity in your app that will be started after successful authentication.